how to calculate the cube roots of complimentary complex numbers
I am currently attempting to calculate the sine and cosine of 1 degree . I have reached the point where I have a lengthy expression containing more roots than a vegetarian stew , but they contain imaginary parts . During a youtube video that I watched , it was claimed that the imaginary parts would cancel each other , but no further explanation was given . In general terms , if I have the expression x=∛(a+bi)+∛(a-bi) how can I show that that a real number will result ? I have tried cubing both sides of the equation , but that didn't seem to work

It depends which cube roots you take. But think geometrically (or in polar form).

Did you mean complementary or conjugate?  A complex number that is unchanged by taking the complex conjugate is real

@karl that was helpful . I can now see very easily that the imaginary parts will cancel . I just need to do the calculations now

If $Z=x±iy$ , then we can write it in the form of $$Z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\bigg(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}±\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\bigg)$$
$$\implies Z=|Z|(\cos t ± i \sin t)$$
Where $t$ is the Amplitude
By Euler form, $Z=|Z|e^{it}$, so
$$\sqrt[3]Z=\sqrt[3]{|Z|}e^{(\frac{t+2kπ}{3})i},k=0,1,2$$
From here, you can calculate the cube root sum,
$$\sqrt[3]Z+\sqrt[3]{\overline{Z}}=\sqrt[3]{|Z|}×2\cos\bigg(\frac{t+2kπ}{3}\bigg),k=0,1,2 $$
